# Как встроить анимацию в заданный размер кнопки

Tags: android, android-animation

Я создал покадровую анимацию в `drawable` файле:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_1" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_2" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_3" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_4" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_5" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_6" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_7" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_8" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_9" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_10" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_11" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_12" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_13" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_14" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_15" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_16" android:duration="300"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_circle_anim_17" android:duration="300"/>
</animation-list>
```

После установки этого файла ресурса в качестве фона кнопки — изображения растягиваются по кнопке, в результате выходит не круг, а низкокачественный овал..) Как сделать, чтобы покадровая анимация располагалась лишь в маленькой части кнопки (к примеру, 50х50dp), а остальное пространство занимало стандартное андроидовское оформление кнопки?

Comment: @metalurgus, а что изменится? Изображение так же растянется.

Comment: А вы пробовали?

Comment: @metalurgus, :o Сработало! Добавьте в ответ :). Но как теперь текст установить....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageButton`, выставить анимацию в `android:src`. Так не будет растягиваться.
Такого класса, чтобы и картинку и текст использовать в `Android SDK` Нет.

Вам никто не запрещает поверх `ImageButton` положить `TextView`, в который и вписать нужный текст

Comment: Я всегда думал, что накладывать виджеты - костыль...

Comment: Главная проблема этого способа в том, что `ImageButton` устанавливает анимацию, а вот как ее запустить.....